# EclipseLink-Bug? Simple native SQL query exception

Tags: eclipselink

I can't execute the following query with EclipseLink:

```
String query = "insert into A_TEST (TEST_NAME) values ('Ain''t it cool? It''s cool, or?')";


    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jdbc-unit");
    EntityManager em = null;

    try {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
        //q.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.FALSE);
        q.executeUpdate();

        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (em != null) {
                if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) 
                    em.getTransaction().rollback();
                em.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Ungültiger Spaltenindex
Error Code: 17003
Call: insert into A_TEST (TEST_NAME) values ('Ain''t it cool? It''s cool, or?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="insert into A_TEST (TEST_NAME) values ('Ain''t it cool? It''s cool, or?)")
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
at persistence.test.ErrorTest.main(ErrorTest.java:43)
```

I've found out that the problem is about the question marks and quotes. If I remove it is works. Also the order of these characters seems to be important.

Does anybody know the issue?

PS: The line "q.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.FALSE);" makes another exception.

---

I've solved it: q.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.TRUE); works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would relay on query parameter to do proper escaping for me. Check [EclipseLink help pages](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native). Passing whole SQL as String may also cause security issues (SQL injections) if part of such a query is user input.

```
query = "insert into A_TEST (TEST_NAME) values (?)";
...
query.setParameter(1, "Ain't it cool? It's cool, or?");
```

Comment: Parameters is a correct way. To be deep, "naive" character quoting doesnt help, for some servers\driver envinromnets should quote `'` as `''` and others as `\'` ... . Unfortunately raw JDBC doesn support my favorite named parameters

Comment: I know it would be better to use prepared statements with parameteres, but I'm used to write SQL in this way. Furthermore I have a helper class to encapsulate the code above and use only a string (SQL) as method argument. Nethertheless I've solved my problem by setting BIND_PARAMETERS=TRUE :) Thanks anyway

Comment: On that case be really sure that you check any user input for dangerous strings like "...; drop database ..."  :)